# Kafka connect to load streaming log data into Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

Is Kafka Spool Directory connector suitable for loading streaming data (log) into Kafka in production ? Can it be run in distributed mode ? Is there any other connector that can be used since filestream source connector is not suitable for production ?

Answer (score 0):

Does this match your requirements?

> provides the capability to watch a directory for files and read the data as new files are written to the input directory.

Do you have CSV or JSON files?

If so, then you can use the [Spooldir connector](https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir)

---

It can be argued that something like Flume, Logastash, Filebeat, FluentD, Syslog, GELF, or other log solutions are more appropriately suited for your purposes of collecting logs into Kafka

Comment: syslog, for example - https://imply.io/post/an-end-to-end-streaming-analytics-stack-for-syslog-data

Comment: thanks....leaning towards using Filebeat ( S3 input ). Do you have any concerns ?

Comment: Looks like that requires SQS as well... Can you not re-route your applications to logging to syslog instead? For example, any service that is started by SystemD will write to syslog from stdout